# SQL Server: Remove substrings from field data by iterating through a table of city names

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, iteration

I have two databases, Database A and Database B.

Database A contains some data which needs to be placed in a table in Database B. However, before that can happen, some of that data must be “cleaned up” in the following way:

The table in Database A which contains the data to be placed in Database B has a field called “Desc.” Every now and then the users of the system put city names in with the data they enter into the “Desc” field. For example: a user may type in “Move furniture to new cubicle. New York. Add electric.”

Before that data can be imported into Database B the word “New York” needs to be removed from that data so that it only reads “Move furniture to new cubicle. Add electric.” However—and this is important—the original data in Database A must remain untouched. In other words, Database A’s data will still read “Move furniture to new cubicle. New York. Add electric,” while the data in Database B will read “Move furniture to new cubicle. Add electric.”

Database B contains a table which has a list of the city names which need to be removed from the “Desc” field data from Database A before being placed in Database B.

How do I construct a stored procedure or function which will grab the data from Database A, then iterate through the Cities table in Database B and if it finds a city name in the “Desc” field will remove it while keeping the rest of the information in that field thus creating a recordset which I can then use to populate the appropriate table in Database B?

I have tried several things but still haven’t cracked it. Yet I’m sure this is probably fairly easy. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

EDIT:

The latest thing I have tried to solve this problem is this:

```
DECLARE @cityName VarChar(50)

While (Select COUNT(*) From ABCScanSQL.dbo.tblDiscardCitiesList) > 0

Begin

Select @cityName = ABCScanSQL.dbo.tblDiscardCitiesList.CityName FROM ABCScanSQL.dbo.tblDiscardCitiesList

SELECT JOB_NO, LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(JOB_NO, (LEN(job_no) -2), 5))) AS  LOCATION
      ,JOB_DESC, [Date_End] , REPLACE(Job_Desc,@cityName,' ') AS NoCity
       FROM fmcs_tables.dbo.Jobt WHERE Job_No like '%loc%'
End
```

"Job_Desc" is the field which needs to have the city names removed.

Comment: You nay want add these *several things* to your post.

Comment: do you have a list of these items(city names) to be replaced? is it stored in a table?

Answer (score 0):

This is a data quality issue.  You can always make a copy of the [description] in Database A and call it [cleaned_desc].

One simple solution is to write a function that does the following.

1 - Read data from [tbl_remove_these_words].  These are the phrases you want removed.

2 - Compare the input - @var_description, to the rows in the table.

3 - Upon a match, replace with a empty string.

This solution depends upon a cleansing table that you maintain and update.

Run a update query that uses the input from [description] with a call to [fn_remove_these_words] and sets [cleaned_desc] to the output.

Another solution is to look at products like Melisa Data (DQ) product for SSIS or data quality services in the SQL server stack to give you a application frame work to solve the problem.